# Find number of populated columns in a single row in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table XXX where it has a number of columns that are increments of a single field.

```
id | FIELD_1 | FIELD_2 | FIELD_3 | FIELD_4 | ... | FIELD_45
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  | "value" | "value" | "value" | " "     | ... |  " "
```

I need to find out the number of fields for each row where the value is not blank.
Is there a way to do it via SQL?

Answer (score 2):

There is, but it is a long expression.  Your data structure looks badly designed.  You should have a table with one row per id and each field.  This is called a junction or association table.

For your problem, you can do:

```
select ((case when field_1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when field_2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when field_3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        . . .
        (case when field_45 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
       ) as NumNonBlank
from XXX;
```

In Oracle, an empty string is treated as a `NULL` value so you use `is not null` for the comparison.